# Form does not shows on clicking using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made form and it is hidden using CSS display property. I have button. I want to show the form when I click that button. I have done everything from my end but still form does not show up.

```
<input type="button" value="Popup" onclick="showLoginForm();"/>

<form id="loginForm" action="" method="post" style="display:none;">
        <p><strong>ID:</strong> </p>
        <strong>Name: *</strong> <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" /><br/>
        <strong>Number: *</strong> <input type="text" id="Number" name="Number" /><br/>
        <strong>Email: *</strong> <input type="text" id=""="Email" name="Email" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" id = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Below is my JS function which is not trigerring.

```
    $("button").click(function(e) {
    $("#loginForm").show();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You don't have a `$("button")` element. However, you do have a `$("input[type=button]")` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `showLoginForm()` is not defined. Your jquery was listening for a button click, when your button is of type input.

```js
$("input[type=button]").click(function(e) {
    $("#loginForm").show();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Popup" />

<form id="loginForm" action="" method="post" style="display:none;">
        <p><strong>ID:</strong> </p>
        <strong>Name: *</strong> <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" /><br/>
        <strong>Number: *</strong> <input type="text" id="Number" name="Number" /><br/>
        <strong>Email: *</strong> <input type="text" id=""="Email" name="Email" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" id = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Or with the function defined:

```js
function showLoginForm(){ 
    $("#loginForm").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Popup" onclick="showLoginForm();"/>

<form id="loginForm" action="" method="post" style="display:none;">
        <p><strong>ID:</strong> </p>
        <strong>Name: *</strong> <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" /><br/>
        <strong>Number: *</strong> <input type="text" id="Number" name="Number" /><br/>
        <strong>Email: *</strong> <input type="text" id=""="Email" name="Email" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" id = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your input is type button, not a button element itself.
so either changing your `input` to a `button` or changing your jquery binding to `$('input[type=button]')` ought to work

http://jsfiddle.net/4Lz5rsq3/